# If ~ is an equivalence relation on A. Show :

Tags: math, set, equivalence

If ~ is an equivalence relation on A. Show :
the unempty subset C of set A is in the equivalance class ~ , iff y & z are in C then y~z.

This is a question I've faced in my homeworks and couldn't find an appropriate proof. I'd be grateful if someone could help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 1) Your question is about pure mathematics, not software engineering, so it doesn't belong on this site -- but it *might* belong on another SE site. 2) We ask that you show an effort to solve the problem yourself. 3) Doesn't it follow directly from the definition of an equivalence class?

Comment: What does "the unempty subset C of set A is in the equivalance class ~" mean? I suspect there are a few words missing from this sentence.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is off-topic here